# Can I Set Device Specific Views using Device.OnPlatform in Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to render device specific views on different platforms in Xaml.

Looking at [this link](http://blog.falafel.com/creating-device-specific-properties-in-cross-platform-apps-with-xamarin-forms/) I can see that I can set properties using `Device.OnPlatform` in Xaml like so:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<OnPlatform x:Key=”standardFont” x:TypeArguments=”Font”>
<OnPlatform.iOS>12</OnPlatform.iOS>
<OnPlatform.Android>12</OnPlatform.Android>
<OnPlatform.WinPhone>18</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
</OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

but I would like to set Views on each platform like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<OnPlatform x:Key=”NumericTextBox” x:TypeArguments=”View”>
<OnPlatform.iOS><sf:NumericTextBox/></OnPlatform.iOS>
<OnPlatform.Android><sf:NumericTextBox/></OnPlatform.Android>
<OnPlatform.WinPhone><Entry/></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
</OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

The reason I need this is because the `Syncfusion NumericTextBox` doesn't work on windows (I have reported this bug but this is a workaround)

Is this possible?

**PS.** I know about Custom Renderers but in this case because there is already a custom renderer for the Syncfusion Numeric Textbox I can't use this technique

Comment: You can create all 3 textboxes and change their visibility in C# using Device.OnPlatform.

Comment: @AlashAmin Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately adding a `Syncfusion Numeric Textbox` to the View breaks the application. But that would be a good idea if that wasnt the case

Comment: You can do one thing, add textboxes from C# code. Create a parent layout and then add these textboxes as child elements.

Comment: Have you actually tried it and verified that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it. You just need to use a ContentView
set its Content property to your Static resource.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XFApp3.Page1">
   <ContentPage.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
       <OnPlatform x:Key=”NumericTextBox” x:TypeArguments=”View”>
       <OnPlatform.iOS><sf:NumericTextBox/></OnPlatform.iOS>
       <OnPlatform.Android><sf:NumericTextBox/></OnPlatform.Android>
       <OnPlatform.WinPhone><Entry/></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
       </OnPlatform>
     </ResourceDictionary>
   </ContentPage.Resources>
   <!-- That's the line you are missing -->
   <ContentView Content="{StaticResource NumericTextBox}" ></ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

And you are ready to enter some numbers.

Comment: I have a smiliar problem, but I need to use DynamicResource for Android and iOS but StaticResource for UWP. Do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question right but you can add your {DinamicResource} in <OnPlatform/> tags. So it would look something like: <OnPlatform.Android> <Label BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource KeyColor}" /></OnPlatform.Android>             <OnPlatform.WinPhone><Label BackgroundColor="{StaticResource KeyColor}" />
                </OnPlatform.WinPhone>

Comment: I already tried this, it was not working, but I came up with another solution. Thank you for responding anyway!